# How to read/export XML file which is output from SQL server in JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I have a Query, which I execute in **SQL server 2005/2008**, gives me output in `XML` format.

Here is the sample query to generate xml output :

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 'White' AS Color1,
            'Blue' AS Color2,
            'Black' AS Color3,
            'Light' AS 'Color4/@Special',
            'Green' AS Color4,
            'Red' AS Color5 
    FOR XML PATH('Colors'),TYPE),
    (SELECT 'Apple' AS Fruits1,
            'Pineapple' AS Fruits2,
            'Grapes' AS Fruits3,
            'Melon' AS Fruits4 
    FOR XML PATH('Fruits'),TYPE) 
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('SampleXML')
```

What I need is, to read the output in **Java** to convert it to a `java.io.File` format, so I can parse and populate objects.

I tried : `SQLXML sqlxml = resultSet.getSQLXML(column);`, which is given in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html)

But it is throwing an exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.pool.g.getSQLXML(I)Ljava/sql/SQLXML;`

Please suggest me a way to read the file.

**Plz Note :** I am able to read the o/p as `String` using `resultSet.getString(column)`, but not able to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

The [SQLXML interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html) provides methods for accessing the XML value as a String, a Reader or Writer, or as a Stream.put the sqlxml into binary stream and parse the xml

```
SQLXML sqlxml = resultSet.getSQLXML(column);
InputStream binaryStream = sqlxml.getBinaryStream();
```

Comment: it is throwing an exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.pool.g.getSQLXML(I)Ljava/sql/SQLXML;

Comment: are you using which version of java?SQLXML is support for java 1.6 version.if your using java 1.6 The dbcp library in server must have been compiled against a previous JDK version which doesn't support XML related methods in the SQL classes